# Virtualbox - limit guest access to certain ips

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, iptables

Is it possible somehow easily to allow guest to connect only to certain ips without making an intermediary linux VM with firewall?

I know I can remove all routes on guest VM and leave only route to certain ips, but I wonder if it can be done in more correct way with VirtualBox tools.

Comment: I don’t think so. I also strongly believe this is not a job the VM software should do.

Comment: Indeed. @OP: Use firewall rules...

Comment: To me it sounds as if there should be a way to configure the VM network such that the host is a router for the guest, and in that case, you should be able to use `iptables` on the host to suppress routing of guest messages to unwanted IP addresses. -- I am suggesting this because I consider it a cleaner approach than restricitng IP addresses on the guest (in many scenarios at least); however, you're not specifying what you would consider a "more correct way" and why. You'll open the door for more helpful answers if you clarify what you're aiming at.